# Search word or word combinations from text file ios

Tags: ios, search, cpu-word, combinations

I am trying to filter words using this code

```
-(BOOL)isBadWord:(NSString*)string{

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wordlist"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

    NSString *delimiter = @"\n";
    NSArray *items = [content componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
    NSString *character = @" ";
    NSArray *searchItems = [string componentsSeparatedByString:character];

    BOOL isContain = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < searchItems.count; i++) {

        if (![[searchItems objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:@""]) {

            NSUInteger indexOfTheObject =[items containsObject:[searchItems objectAtIndex:i]];

            if (indexOfTheObject > 0) {
                isContain = true;
            }
        }
     }
    return isContain;
}
```

This is ok for single words, but if combination of words in the text file it not works. eg:
    string = word1 {space} word2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically need to do is to iterate an array of bad words/combinations and for each of these steps you should search for this combination on your `string` like this:

```
BOOL isContain = NO;
for (NSString *badWord in items) {
    if ([string rangeOfString:badWord].location != NSNotFound) {
        isContain = YES;
        break;
    }
}
return isContain;
```

Please note that `BOOL` can be `YES` and `NO`, but not `true` and `false` — it is a special scalar type you should use in Objectve-C when working with Cocoa/CocoaTouch.

Cheers! :)

P.S. it seems you do a lot of work with strings, it may be useful for you to see [this String Programming Guide's chapter by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI).